# What's the purpose of ssh-ed25519-cert-v01?

Tags: ssh

I've been playing around with OpenSSH (7.4p1-10 on Debian 9) crypto settings and noticed, that when I set in sshd_config

```
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

and have a host key generated with

```
ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key -t ssh-ed25519
```

the server complains:

```
debug3: list_hostkey_types: ssh-ed25519 key not permitted by HostkeyAlgorithms [preauth]
```

Interestingly ssh-keygen -t takes ssh-ed25519-cert-v01 as parameter, but fails to generate a key. 
What is the purpose of this algorithm? Where can I find more information about it?

```
# ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key -N '' -t "ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com"
Generating public/private ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com key pair.
key_generate failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ssh-keygen` manual page has a section on "certificates."

OpenSSH certificates are conceptually similar to X.509 (SSL/TLS) certificates – the client or server trusts one key to act as a *certification authority,* automatically accepting all servers' or users' pubkeys *signed by that key.* (Unlike X.509, the OpenSSH cert format only supports direct trust, not transitive; there can be no "intermediate" CAs.)

Even though 7.4 mistakenly accepts the certificate formats in `-t`, it doesn't make sense to generate them that way. First you need to generate a *plain* keypair (currently all types are supported), then use `ssh-keygen -s ... [-h|-u] ...` to sign the public key with the CA keypair, which outputs a certificate.

*(In theory it would be possible for `ssh-keygen` to generate the keypair and immediately sign it, but it wouldn't make sense from a security PoV – there is no need for the CA to ever have access to the private key, much less worry about distributing it to the user/server. Let the user/server generate their own keypair instead.)*